# Receive drops on an disabled SWT widget

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, swt

how can I create a SWT widget, in my case a StyledText, that can recieve Drop events even while being disabled.

```
textPane = new StyledText(parent, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.MULTI | SWT.WRAP);
textPane.setEnabled(false);
DropTarget target = new DropTarget(textPane, DND.DROP_DEFAULT | DND.DROP_MOVE);
target.setTransfer(new Transfer[] {TextTransfer.getInstance(),FileTransfer.getInstance()});
    target.addDropListener(new DropTargetAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void drop(DropTargetEvent event) {
            System.out.println(event);
        }
    });
```

Now the created textPane will not be able to recieve drop events. If I remove the `textPane.setEnabled(false)` it works again. How can I get this to work always?

Thank you very much^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *might* work, I can't test it at the moment: create a (enabled) `Composite` with `FillLayout` as the parent of your disabled component, and handle drop events there.